# How to expose WhenAny etc

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I'm sure I've missed something or backed myself into some strange frustrated corner, but here is what I'm trying to do.

I have a WPF application, using Unity as IoC. I have a number of services that have an interface. I deal with my services via the interfaces so the services can be swapped out easily or so that I can offer a choice to the end-user. All standard interface programming stuff.

In reality, all my services implement ReactiveObject. I am now wanting to do some command handling stuff and am trying to get the CanExecute behaviour working.

My basic problem is I cannot use WhenAny unless I cast the interface to a physical implementation (thus get the full type hierarchy for compilation, which can see WhenAny). However, this cast violates interfaces and means I lose the ability to swap out implementations.

Is there a ReactiveUI interface that exposes WhenAny etc that I could derive my service interfaces from and thus be able to use the great features of ReactiveUI whilst remaining non-type specific?

Comment: There's no need to add personal greetings in the questions. Your contact card is displayed at the bottom right of all your questions.

Comment: Sorry, it's the first time I asked a question and have never noticed no-one else does it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you use WhenAny on an instance that is an interface? As of ReactiveUI 4.x, WhenAny should be on *every* object.

If you're still using 3.x, you can write your interfaces like this:

```
interface ICoolInterface : IReactiveNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, so if my service interface inherits from that IReactive interface, I should get the WhenAny etc extensions? I shall give this a try later and confirm.

Comment: Worked a treat. I will upgrade to the latest version though to grab fixes and features.